# XCode - iPhone SDK Zombies

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, nszombie

Is NSZombiesEnabled supported when debugging applications built with a target of the iPhone SDK 3.x?

Also if it is supported, is there anywhere I can get a list of the possible levels supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is supported for both device and simulator.

It's "NSZombieEnabled" though (not Zombies).  You set it by right-clicking on the executable and selecting the General then Environments section - set the value to "YES".  If you want to disable it (and you do for any production build) uncheck the variable.

Comment: Odd that Instruments won't let you use it for device-targeted builds then; it only allows zombies for the simulator.